# php mail() function fails when $to field is from mysqli object. cpanel server

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to email a message to an address i queried using `$mysqli->query` from a database using the `mail()` function in PHP. The `mail()` function returns true, but i'm not getting any emails. Here is a portion of my code:

```
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        $obj = $result->fetch_object();
        $to = $obj->email;
    }

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I'm sure  the other parameters (`$subject, $message, $headers`) are set just fine because I can get an email when i hardcode the variable by replacing the line `$to = $obj->email;` with `$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';`

I also tried `strcmp($to, 'myemail@gmail.com')` and it returns zero. meaning there's no difference in the strings.

**UPDATE:**

As someone suggested, I tried to look into the logs. Here are some portions of it:

```
 Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
host mx-apac.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net [106.10.166.52]:
421 4.7.1 [TS03] All messages from 64.120.250.230 will be permanently deferred; Retrying will NOT succeed. See http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts03.html

No action is required on your part. Delivery attempts will continue for
some time, and this warning may be repeated at intervals if the message
remains undelivered. Eventually the mail delivery software will give up,
and when that happens, the message will be returned to you.
```

In another log this is what it says:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
xxxxxxx@yahoo.com
retry time not reached for any host after a long failure period
```

Now I still have no idea why the the email sends just fine when I hardcode the email in the `to` parameter of the `mail` function.

also, the codes `var_dump($to)` and `var_dump(trim($to))` yields the same results

Comment: So you are sure `$to` is `'myemail@gmail.com'`? Why not place the `mail` within the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure that $to is the correct email. Placing the `mail` within the `if` statement doesn't solve anything, plus the email sends correctly if I replace the line with the `mail()` function, with `mail('myemail@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);` so I'm wondering why it doesn't work (but still returns true) when `$to = $obj->email`

Comment: You need to `var_dump($to)` because it looks like it doesn't contain the correct value

Comment: What does you mailserver log say?

Comment: I didn't know such thing existed! thanks. I've updated my question to include the logs.

Comment: Are you comparing delivery to `@gmail.com` vs. `@yahoo.com`?

Comment: try trim-ing the address, `$to = trim($to);`

Comment: the var_dump results looks alright. var_dump($to) prints: `string(24) "xxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com.ph"`

Comment: Well, first you said the address is gmail, so make up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Have you even bothered to read the log?

It tells you right there why it is not being delivered and even where you can get more information about it.